# What are better practices in ER modeling?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am developing a twitter based application for technical support for a company

so, the workflow is about like this

1- Twitter user mentions the company.

2- The admin gets notified.

3- Starts to use DMs with customer.

so, I am a little bit confused about best ER model.

Should I have tweets and DMs stored in the same table or should I separate them, for the sake of getting thousands of records?

Comment: So #1 is the support topic and #3 is the following discussion? What is a DM?

Comment: In Twitter terms a DM is a private message, is looks the same but is only visible for a user. In essence it is the same as a normal tweet but with a receiver_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has few entities, user_id means the ID of the user who writes the tweet:

**Basic structure**

```
Message (id, message, user_id, date etc)
User (id, name, employee_id?, etc)
```

**Single account mentioned**

Then you have the fact that a mention could take place, that is an attribute to a message so you could add a column for that like: BOOL mentioned if you only want to have one account. Would give:

```
Message (id, message, user_id, date, BOOL mentioned, etc)
User (id, name, employee?, etc)
```

**Multiple Accounts can be mentioned**

Another form could be more flexible, add a table accounts which allows to store the accounts you want the mentions of:

```
Account (id, name)
Message (id, message, user_id, date, INT account_mentioned, etc)
User (id, name, employee?, etc)
```

That gives more flexibility because you could just add an Account and start following the mentions, you could for example notify the admin of that Account making your solution more future proof.

**How to deal with employees**

Depending on your workflow you can say: An employee is a User which handles one or more Accounts. Also you could state that one Account is managed by multiple Users and finally the situation where multiple Users manage multiple Accounts.

In essence I would suggest to make a connecting table:

```
Accounts_Users (account_id, user_id)
```

You could even add roles in that table or a priority for example. That gives you full control of the accounts. Because no information on this part was given I cannot explain it in total.

**Storing DM's and public messages**

Then you have the issue of DM's, that could be most easily be appended to the Message entity:

```
Account (id, name)
Message (id, message, user_id, user_to_id (NULLABLE), date, INT account_mentioned_id, etc)
User (id, name, employee?, etc)
```

So by default for a message (tweet) the user_to_id column is NULL but when it is a DM you add there the receiver. That way you can find them.

Why put them all in one table? It is the same entity with the same attributes, it only has a flag (private) but it is in essence the same data.

**The amount of data**

...is totally irrelevant at this stage. In essence you just need the right structure, so normalize it first. If you really see performance issues then take a look at how the de-normalize some steps but I don't expect, for a single company use, you would run into issues with this normalized structure.

You only need normal simple joins to get the data you want and because it is normalized you can also easily create for example a page showing all communication with one User (client) because you normalized. That data is easy to get with this setup.

We have several millions of tweets handled and you can just normalize, no problem really. The data is not very big so lots of rows is not expensive.

**Final setup advised**

I would go this way based on the information I have now.

```
Account (id, name)
Accounts_Users (account_id, user_id)
Message (id, message, user_id, user_to_id (NULLABLE), date, account_mentioned_id, etc)
User (id, name, etc)
```